# cleaning up function looping

Tags: python, recursion

I am looping a function in python as I created my own constant listener. My question is how can I ensure I don't overflow / crash? Logically this is telling me I am leaving a lot of open functions in the background. Once parameters of my application are met I `exit(0)` for a clean shut down. but how can I ensure this doesn't eat up memory?

This code works fine btw, but I am simply trying to improve it because it feels really wrong to me that I am calling the function within its self without closing the previous use of it and it just feels dirty. constructive comments please.

e.g. (this is now my actual code)

```
import serial
import sys
import time
def enterdata():
     ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
     ser.write("\r")
     time.sleep(0.5)
     while True:
         data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
         if (len(data) > 0):
             a = []
             for i in range(len(data)):
                 a.append(data[i])
                 if "Please press Enter to activate this console." in "".join(a):
                     print ("1")
                     exit(0)
                     break
      ser.close()
      enterdata()
ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
ser.write("\r\n")
enterdata()
```

NEW VERSION SO FAR FROM POSTS MADE:

```
import serial
import sys
import time
def enterdata():
 ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
 ser.write("\r")
 time.sleep(0.5)
 while True:
  data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
  if (len(data) > 0):
   a = []
   for i in range(len(data)):
    a.append(data[i])
    if "Please press Enter to activate this console." in "".join(a):
     print ('1')
     return True
     exit(0)
   break
 ser.close()
ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
ser.write("\r\n")
state = False
while state is not True:
 state = enterdata()
```

Comment: This is called infinite recursion

Comment: Well.. you seem to be calling `funName` **a lot**.

Comment: What is your aim? Print `hello` an infinite number of times? Please give us the expected output

Comment: ok il update it with the real code so you can see my aim.

Comment: Call the function iteratively in a loop controlled by some condition or simply checking a `finished` flag.

Comment: I have updated... you can now see I am listening for a serial output and checking the return untill I get a specific response... then printing 1 and exiting

Comment: "(obviously not my actual code)" obviously...

Comment: Why are you calling `enterdata()` inside `enterdata()` *inside* a `while True` loop? You want a recursive succession of `while True` loops?

Comment: @khelwood I am not calling the function from the while loop, its on the outside of the while loop (I messed up my tabbing a bit when moving it on here, I will fix that) I am simply listening to the incoming breaking the while loop and restarting the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code you showed will give a "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" Error because of Python sets a default value for how many recursions can occur in one function at a time.

Any yours is infinite and definitely will cause problems even if you change this default limit.

Why not make a loop yourself and call the function at will ?

```
found = False
while not found:
    extracted_data = lookfordata()
    if extracted_data == "I want it to be equal to this":
        found = True
```

I see you edited the post. Whatever you are trying to do, that method is not efficent, not recommended and not pretty. All the good reasons not to use it.

Imagine that you will handle some data larger than you are using now, you won't know if the recursion stopping condition will come to pass before you exceed the limit. It's also no use to increase limit all the time you encounter a bigger data. I think it should be any programmer's goal to avoid repetition and coming up with programs that can handle any type of unexpected input.

You updated your post again. This way of input handling is much better than raw recursion. Just to mention, instead of;

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    a.append(data[i])
```

use

```
for i in data:
    a.append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, could you expand a bit? Im new to python...so like ? while varible is not true: ? as you can see I updated with functional code

Comment: Take a look at the new example.

Comment: ah ok, I did this before but I had outputs writing to the screen (they were blank for not putting a range meant loads of empty bytes being printed, hence why I did this, though I will change now! thanks)